# linkedin connectivity from my native iphone application

Tags: iphone, linkedin-api

hello everyone i am new bie in iphone development i want to connect to linkedin from my native iphone application i am currently having no idea how to connect to it please guide me how could i do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.zhangkf.com/2010/06/linkedin-developer-network-oauth-authentication/:

> Yes you can get connected with Linedin withyour Native Application by
>   following simple steps:
>
> 1. You get an API key from LinkedIn. This is also called a Consumer Key in OAuth terminology.
> 2. You build a feature into your site that leverages the user's LinkedIn network.
> 3. Your user clicks on your UI to request to use that feature.
> 4. You make a call to LinkedIn to ask to use our authentication. This is called getting a Request Token.
> 5. LinkedIn replies with an OAuth Token indicating that you can use the authentication system.
> 6. You send your user to a LinkedIn URL. That URL includes the OAuth Token you got and a few other parameters such as a URL for LinkedIn to
>      return the user to after granting access.
> 7. The user grants access to your application by signing into that page.
> 8. Upon successful signon, LinkedIn will return the user to your site.
> 9. You will then make a call to LinkedIn to get an Access Token.
> 10. LinkedIn replies with an Access Token for the user. You use that Access Token for any API calls to LinkedIn to identify the user on
>       whose behalf you are making the call.

Or

Download the Code from here,you could get it.Just Provide your API Key and Secrete Key

http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

Or see this for details:

http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008

Comment: Yeh ! It seems to be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

This sample is 100% complete and working, just add your app key.

- Built with the latest XCode 4.01.
- Uses a UIWebView so you have the option of customizing the browser UI.
- **Uses JSON instead of XML**, which is the preferred best practice for most cases
- OAuth is heavily documented so you know what's happening
- Tested with iPhone 4, iPad 1, and the simulator on iOS 4.x.

http://lee.hdgreetings.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth.html