# How can i post a blog on LinkedIn?

Tags: iphone

I want to post a blog on linkedIn so how it's possible?I have completed LogIn functionality in LinkedIn.Please Help me in Posting blog from my native application.if some one got the idea then please explain me with code.i have completed authentication process but after authentication successful it gives me one code like "61592".and Message like this:"You have successfully authorized [AppName].Please return to your application and enter following security code to grant access: 61592 "

Comment: @Ankit Could you please provide more details about what, specifically, you're trying to do and how it is a programming issue.

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: I believe he wants to create a blog post from a native iPhone app.

Comment: That'd be a cool question, but I think we're just wishing this one made sense.

Comment: I want to post some Text Message from my native application and it should be posted in LinkedIn's Wall and every one should read it.Like facebook we can post our message to facebook's wall.

Comment: superuser's already got one [(user crossposted)](http://superuser.com/questions/140597/can-any-one-please-tell-me-how-can-i-connect-to-linkedin-from-my-nativa-applicati) ... @Berkay: when you post a comment that a question belongs on another Trilogy site, you should inform the OP that the question can be migrated automatically, and that they should not crosspost.  thanks!

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085048/how-can-i-integrate-linkedin-within-an-iphone-application and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809036/linkedin-connectivity-from-my-native-iphone-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make blog posts appear in your LinkedIn feed, the easiest way to do this is to use another blog and have it syndicated on LinkedIn. For example if you have a blog on http://posterous.com you can send posts to your blog via email and have it autopost to your LinkedIn  profile, by configuring up the "Autopost" options in "Settings" on posterous.com.

Comment: No Actually i don't want to do like that when i go for the Registration and if it will get succeed then automatically the content which i have should posed on LinkedIn Wall.

Comment: I really can't understand the question then. The method I suggested would automatically post the content on the LinkedIn wall. The same thing happens if you syndicate your Twitter feed. My LinkedIn profile works this way, if you want to see an example: http://uk.linkedin.com/in/snim2

Comment: can you give me the Sample code for posting some content on Wall of LinkedIn.Actually i got the above message with security code from that i don't understand what to do?i can give you my sample code if you want?i have never implemented before it that's why i don't understand please understand my situation.

Comment: I think it would clarify your question a lot if you posted the sample code.

The solution I was suggesting didn't actually require any code. Are you writing an application?

Comment: http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone
You can get the Sample code from here and In this code you have to provide API key and Secrete key and you can understand the problem.IT will give you authentication Only.