# While providing Username and Password LinkedIn comes out my native application?

Tags: iphone

I am new in this field.i am integrating LinkedIn in my native application.While i am providing user name and password it comes out my native application and opens the LinkedIn site so please help me. if any one has sample code for posting a blog on wall then please give me i am really needed it.

Comment: have you read the faq?  It asks that your question: be detailed and specific, written clearly and simply and be of interest to other programmers.  Perhaps you could also accept some of your other questions...

Comment: I just want to Integrate LinkedIn in my Native application but i don't know the Procedure so if you have any kind of idea then please give me.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824368/how-can-i-post-a-blog-on-linkedin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to use [LinkedIn API](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis).

Comment: I have taken sample code from:http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone but i am not able to post blog it comes out my native application.